# how to scroll position of webengineview in qt 5.9.6

Tags: qt, qml, qwebengineview

I'm running the minimal webengineview example and I inserted a button to move the page down. The code is below. I tried using scrollPosition but it seems scroll position is used only to get the scrolling position. Is there a way to link the button click to the position on the page? Thanks

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
     width: 1024
     height: 750
     visible: true

Rectangle {

    anchors.fill: parent


    WebEngineView {
        id:page
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "http://www.qt.io"
        }

    Button {
        id: buttondown

        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }

        width: 100
        height: 50
        text: "DOWN"
        onClicked:{
                    page.scrollPosition(1,1)

                }

    }
```

}

}

Comment: [scrollPosition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#scrollPosition-prop) is a property of type `point`, not a function. You should probably do something like `page.scrollPosition = Qt.point(1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

edited the qml file like this and now the page generally is scrolled.
But if the html to show has index.html the page is not scrolled properly.
Someone knows why?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 750
    visible: true

    Rectangle {

        anchors.fill: parent


        WebEngineView {
            id:web
            anchors.fill: parent
            url: "http://www.qt.io"
            }

        Button {
            id: buttondown

            anchors {
                bottom: parent.bottom
                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
             }

            width: 100
            height: 50
            text: "DOWN"
            onClicked:{
                    
                web.runJavaScript("window.scrollBy(%1,%2);".arg(0).arg(10));

                }

    }
```

}

}

Comment: please avoid posting another question as an answer, create a new one